# MySQL separate two tables in common query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

I have a website where users can review let's say 'fruits' and 'vegetables'.
I have a fruit_review and a vegetable_review table. Both have reviewId, fruitName/vegetableName, reviewText and date fields.

I would like to make a "last 5 reviews" section on my index page for example.

To do this, I use the following query:

```
SELECT reviewId AS id, fruitName AS name, reviewText AS text, date FROM fruit_review
UNION
SELECT reviewId AS id, vegetableName AS name, reviewText AS text, date FROM vegetable_review
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;
```

This works well, but I would like to use these results as a link to the review.

**How can I decide if the reviews I just got are belong to fruits or vegetables?**(href="vegetablereview.php?id=$id" or href="fruitreview.php?id=$id" for each case?)

Can I include something to the query, which gives back for example the table's name what I can handle in php?

I would not like to add any extra columns to the tables (for example a type column which is always 0 for fruits and 1 for vegetables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well use `union all`.  It is more efficient:

```
SELECT 'fruit' as which, reviewId AS id, fruitName AS name, reviewText AS text, date FROM fruit_review
UNION ALL
SELECT 'vegetable' as which, reviewId AS id, vegetableName AS name, reviewText AS text, date FROM vegetable_review
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

In other words, you have to handle it explicitly.  MySQL doesn't have the ability to identify the table for a particular column, unless you specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom field (type) and fill it with the Text Fruit or Vegetable for each line.

```
SELECT reviewId AS id, fruitName AS name, 'fruit' as type, reviewText AS text, date FROM fruit_review
UNION
SELECT reviewId AS id, vegetableName AS name, 'vegetable' as type, reviewText AS text, date FROM vegetable_review
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;
```